# Why am I getting an access violation when assigning values to a structure in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I am getting an Access violation with this code after it compiles. I have tried a few other methods to be able to get this to work and my results vary from just getting an address printed out to a number being printed when trying to print a string.

What I am trying to do is declare an array of pointers to a structure so I can store many students information.

Any advice regarding how I can get this working would be much appreciated.
thanks in advance!

```
// Assignment 10 (2).cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 25
#define SIZE_FNAME 15
#define SIZE_LNAME 15

void clear(void);

/*********************************************************************************
Structure Student: Defines and holds all the variables for the information required
to run the Student Program

Input:
N/A

Output:
N/A
*********************************************************************************/
struct student
{
    char* firstName;
    char* lastName;
    double* gradeAvg;
};
typedef struct student;

/*********************************************************************************
Function Main:

Input:
N/A

Output:
N/A
*********************************************************************************/
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    struct student *pStudent = (student*)malloc(sizeof(student));
    pStudent->firstName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * SIZE_FNAME);
    pStudent->lastName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) *SIZE_LNAME);
    pStudent->gradeAvg = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double));
    if (pStudent == NULL)
    {
        printf("No mem");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("Enter first name: ");
    scanf("%14s", pStudent->firstName, SIZE_FNAME);
    printf("%s", pStudent->firstName);
    clear();

    printf("Enter last name: ");
    scanf("%14s", pStudent->lastName, SIZE_LNAME);
    printf("%s", pStudent->lastName);
    clear();

    printf("Enter grade average: ");
    scanf("%lf", pStudent->gradeAvg);
    printf("%lf", *pStudent->gradeAvg);
    clear();
}
void clear(void)
{
    while (getchar() != '\n');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this is C file, save it as file.c, not file.cpp. Your compiler looks at the extension to decide what compiler to use.

**I see 12 errors.**

Look for the ^ characters in the code below.

```
struct student *pStudent = (student*)malloc(sizeof(student));
                           ^^^^^^^^^^ remove this
pStudent->lastName = malloc(sizeof(char)*SIZE_LNAME); // add this line
*pStudent->firstName = (char)malloc(sizeof(char)*SIZE_FNAME);
^ remove this          ^^^^^^ remove this
if (pStudent == NULL)
    printf("No mem");
    // add an exit here, don't continue

printf("Enter first name: ");
scanf_s("14%s", *pStudent->firstName, SIZE_FNAME);
                ^ remove this         ^^^^^^^^^^ add this
printf("%d", pStudent->firstName);
         ^ should be s
clear();

printf("Enter last name: ");
scanf_s("14%s", *pStudent->lastName, SIZE_LNAME );
                ^ remove this        ^^^^^^^^^^ add this
clear();

printf("Enter grade average: ");
scanf_s("14%s", pStudent->gradeAvg);
         ^^^^ should be %lf
clear();
printf("%d", pStudent->gradeAvg);
         ^ should be %lf
```

Comment: From the microsoft documentation about `scanf_s`, "Unlike scanf and wscanf, scanf_s and wscanf_s require the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or [. The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable. For example, if reading a string, the buffer size for that string is passed as follows: `scanf_s("%9s", s, 10); // buffer size is 10, width specification is 9`.

Comment: What is the %lf doing? i've never seen the annotation before

Comment: @Mack: `%lf` is the format string for a long float, usually known as a double.

Comment: Ah ok, Well I also tried this line of code
   *pStudent->firstName = (char)malloc(sizeof(char)*SIZE_FNAME);
   ^ remove this          ^^^^^^ remove this 
And i'm getting error of void pointer not being able to be assign to a char *

Comment: Oh crap, does microsoft require malloc to be cast? Oh, it's a C++ vs C issue. Is this supposed to be C or C++?

Comment: It is C

But I think Microsoft does require it to be cast because I have yet to be able to write a malloc with out a cast.

Comment: No, casting malloc in C is not suggested.

Comment: @CharlieBurns: Honestly, I'm not sure. I've never used `scanf_s` myself before. You can check this out for microsoft's documentation on it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @CharlieBurns: Ok so I got almost all of it working, but lastName is returning lines of garbage when printed. I followed the same format as the firstName. 

I can edit my original post to show what I have done
Edit: Changes have been made in OP

Answer (score 3):

To allocate memory for the `firstname` field, you should do this:

```
pStudent->firstName = malloc(sizeof(char) * SIZE_FNAME);
```

To scanf a string, you should do this *(note, `scanf_s` is a microsoft specific change to the normal `scanf`, requiring special arguments)*:

```
scanf_s("%14s", pStudent->firstName, SIZE_FNAME);
```

You also need to allocate memory for the lastname.

Comment: Yea, I'm working in VS2013 and it throws a fit when I don't use scanf_s

But I am getting a void* cannot be assigned to char* error when I try and change the first name allocation line

Comment: @Mack, save your file as file.c, not file.cpp.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to *sharth's* answer,

`scanf_s("14%s", *pStudent->lastName);`

For doing this first allocate memory to lastname also as you did for `firstname`.

Answer (score 0):

`->` is higher precedence than `*` so `*pStudent->firstName = ...` evaluates to `*(pStudent->firstName) = ...` which would obviously cause an access error when trying to dereference firstName, which probably has a value of 0.

Also, as sharth noted you don't need the `*` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

even it is not mentioned clearly where you getting error, But looking at code I think you getting error at

```
*pStudent->firstName = (char)malloc(sizeof(char)*SIZE_FNAME);
```

change this to

```
pStudent->firstName = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*SIZE_FNAME);
```